# Error: constructor must explicitly initialize reference member

Tags: c++, oop, reference

I have the following files:

car.h

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace CarLibrary { 

  class Car   {
    private:
      string& _producer; 
      string& _model;
      string& _color;

    public:
      Car(const string& producer,
          const string& model,
          const string& color);  

      string Show();

  };
```

car.cpp

```
#include "car.h"

namespace CarLibrary {

Car::Car(const string& producer,
         const string& model,
         const string& color)
{  
    _producer = producer;
    _model = model;
    _color = color;
}

string Car::Show()
{
    return _model + " (" + _producer + "): color " + _color ;
}

}
```

I am getting these errors:

C:...\car.cpp:5: error: constructor for 'CarLibrary::Car' must explicitly initialize the reference member '_producer'

C:..\car.cpp:5: error: constructor for 'CarLibrary::Car' must explicitly initialize the reference member '_model'

C:...\car.cpp:5: error: constructor for 'CarLibrary::Car' must explicitly initialize the reference member '_color'

I am following a videolecture, repeating what the professor is doing and the weird thing is that the professor is not getting any error, even though I am just copying exactly the same code.
Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Double check: are you sure that the working code defines the members of `Car` like `string& _model` and not like `string _model`?

Comment: @JaMiT  thanks, that was it. It is actually string _model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reference must be initialized to reference something.

Here you try to assign to the references after they have already been created. That's not legal:

```
Car::Car(const string& producer,
         const string& model,
         const string& color)
{  
    _producer = producer;
    _model = model;
    _color = color;
}
```

The solution is to use the member initializer list:

```
Car::Car(const string& producer,
         const string& model,
         const string& color) : // colon indicates the start of the member init list
    _producer(producer),
    _model(model),
    _color(color)
{
    // constructor body - now empty
}
```

Note: For this to work, your member reference variables also need to be `const`.
Reference members are usually *not* what you want. I suggest making them into normal `std::string`s.

Comment: The weird thing is that in the video, it works for my professor, with no errors. I am using the same code he has provided and using the same IDE(qtcreator ) and compiler. The only difference being that he is on Linux and I am on Windows, but I don't think this makes any difference, does it? How is it possible?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Are you sure the data members in `Car` are references and not objects? e.g. is it `string& _producer;` or is it `string _producer;`?

Comment: @Kevin it was  string _producer actually

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, was this what you meant with " I suggest making them into normal std::strings."

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Yes, exactly.

Comment: So , when using reference member variables, there are constraints to  pay attention to? supposing I did wanted member reference variables, why does making them into const string& solves the problem?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO You take `const&` as arguments to your constructor, that's why they need to be `const&`. If your constructor had taken them as non-`const&`, you could keep the members non-`const`. Stil, reference members are tricky and very rarely what you want.